# Omitir el puerto en dirección URL NodeJS

Tags: nodejs, webservice

les escribo porque tengo el siguiente problema
Subi mi aplicacion de nodeJS que envia correos electronicos y funciona en el puerto 3000. Mi inconveniente es que para ir a mi pagina tiene que ser de esta manera [www.mipagina.com:3000](http://www.mipagina.com:3000) y yo quisiera que me ayudaran para poder hacer que quede [www.mipagina.com](http://www.mipagina.com) si necesidad de colocar el puerto por el cual esta escuchando.
les comparto mi codigo en github
https://github.com/dtrujillog/correo.git

Comment: Te damos la bienvenida a Stack Overflow, te recomiendo que leas [cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) y de paso realiza el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida ¡Y obtendrás tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/what-are-badges)! Si tienes dudas, puedes consular el [Centro de ayuda](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help). Añade el código que da error y lo que hayas intentado

Comment: Tienes que redireccionar desde tu servidor.

Answer (score 0):

Para poder hacer lo que quieres, debes

- Redireccionar las peticiones entrantes al puerto `80` o `443` en el servidor que recibe las peticiones hacia el servidor que procesa las peticiones, en este caso hacer una redirección a dicho servidor al puerto `3000`. Puedes usar un reverse proxy o simplemente cambiar la configuración de red para hacer un port-forwarding.
- Colocar el servidor que procesa las peticiones en el puerto `80` o `443`.

¿Por qué en esos puertos? Ese es el estándard, los navegadores si ven que en la URI hace falta el puerto, simplemente se lo agregan. `80` si la URL comienza con `http`, `443` si comienza con `https`.

Esto es asumiendo claramente que estamos hablando de servicios http, si no es así, solamente los puertos cambian, la solución propuesta es la misma.